# How can I get all accounts concern with a e-mail account?

Tags: email, search, find

Some social networking have an option: find all friends via a e-mail account. So how does it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. it requires your email account password
2. the social network enters your email account and fetches the contact list
3. it compares your list with its database of registered profiles (specifically, with the email of the registered users)
4. every match is a person which you have had contact with in the past.
5. All of those matches are proposed to you as friend.

This is more or less how it works.

Comment: It only requires your password if it is &^$%. The terms of service of most email services forbid people handing it out. Most popular webmail services provide APIs to share contacts. e.g. [Yahoo!](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/), [Google](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/).